# I am unable to figure out whether the Negative Flag or Overflow Flag will be set here

Tags: assembly, avr, flags, signed

I am treating the data as signed numbers. My Professor taught me that BRLT conditional is fulfilled when Sign Flag is set to 1. I am not able to figure out how Sign Flag shows 1 in my calculation here using the code of AVR in Assembly Language.

My code:

`LDI R16,0b11111111`
(storing the number -128 into Register 16)

`LDI R17,0b00000001`
(storing +1 into Register 1 and negative of -1 in signed number is 10000001)

`LOOP:`
(defining Loop subroutine)

`SUB R16,R17`
(subtracting data in R16 from R17 and storing the result in R16 which should be -129 but that is out of range, as I am calculating using signed numbers the result should be 10000000)

`CPI R16,0b00000000`
(the result in R16 which is 10000000. When compared to 00000000, R16-0 is
calculated which is 00000000. This will not set negative flag  and also won't set the
overflow flag. As Sign Flag is XOR of V and N, S should be 0. But that was
not the case. Apparently S Flag is 1 here. I am not able to understand how.)

`BRLT LOOP`
(if Sign Flag is 1, BRLT is satisfied and we will go back up to where LOOP started)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know "the code of AVR in Assembly language". Thus I assume the following:

- You use an 8-bit architecture.
- If you have a 2-operand instruction, the left operand is the destination of the operation.
- You use 2's complement integers.

Then:
`LDI R16,0b11111111` loads -1 decimal into R16.
`LDI R17,0b00000001` loads +1 decimal into R17.
`SUB R16,R17` computes `0b11111111 - 0b00000001 = 0b11111110` and stores it in R16. `0b11111110` is -2 decimal.
`CPI R16,0b00000000` computes `0b11111110 - 0b00000000 = 0b11111110`, -2 decimal. Thus the negative flag is set.
Maybe this does not apply to your architecture, but only to my assumptions.

Comment: What is the meaning of "We use 2s complement integers"?  For signed numbers, as the first bit already represents positive or negative, why do we even need to 2s complement it? As far as I know, 2s complement is a replacement to signed numbers. @Reinhard Männer

Comment: You do not need to but it is a convenient encoding. Other formats include sign-and-magnitude (which is what you describe) and one's complement.

Comment: Yes, AVR is an 8-bit 2's complement RISC machine, with 2-operand instructions.  http://atmel-studio-doc.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/webhelp/GUID-0B644D8F-67E7-49E6-82C9-1B2B9ABE6A0D-en-US-1/index.html is an ISA reference.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmel_AVR_instruction_set

Comment: @Jester: The question expects `0xff` to represent `-128`.  8-bit sign/magnitude and one's complement can only represent a value-range of [-127, +127], but yeah, wrapping the low 7 bits on `CHAR_MIN - 1` and keeping the sign bit set seems more like sign/magnitude than anything else.

Comment: @RKEshat: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement for how bit-patterns represent signed values in AVR.